# Django syncdb - How does it know if it previously created the tables or if I did?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-postgresql

I manually created some tables in Postgre for a Django project. I manually created the model too. When I try to `syncdb`, it throws a database error and says the table already exists.

If syncdb creates the table previously, this won't happen. How does syncdb know whether it created the table or if I created the table?

Comment: Why are you creating the tables manually? If you need to have initial data in your database you should be using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: There's no difference between syncdb creating the table and you creating it. Syncdb isn't very clever when it comes to intermediary tables though, eg for a ManyToManyField. Can you post some model and sql code?

Comment: @toto_tico I had already created the tables a long time ago. I figured there was a better way to do this, but I was just wondering how syncdb knew whether the table that happened to be there was one it created or one I created. I didn't know about fixtures. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Greg If there is no difference why is syncdb complaining the tables already exist. Shouldn't it assume it was the one who created them?

Comment: @JohnRambo, read the rest of my comment please...

Comment: @JohnRambo, I am curious about your question. @Greg is right pointed out that syncdb is quite basic. For the same reason I think even a simple difference in the tables could cause troubles (e.g.,  deleting a column). I definitely think that your best approach here is to go with the fixtures. You can dump in SQL format `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` and create the fixtures from that.  You may also be interested in (South)[http://south.aeracode.org/] for migrations in the database. I always try to avoid using it until production though.

Comment: @Greg I haven't posted my code because I've changed it quite a lot since I originally posted this and only figured out how to use git about a week ago. I don't think it matters though. If you manually create a table and then create a model to match, syncdb will complain the table already exists. How does it know?, especially if it so basic. It 's not really important any more since South can figure it out. I'm just curious now. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I manually created the model too`

Comment: I executed the SQL statements with psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems django maintains an internal cache of apps and their models. It is from here that it knows if it has already created a table for a model or not.  I suppose this is why there is support for [introspection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models), so that the models are created from existing schemas and the cache is properly populated.

From the [syncdb source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py#L58) it is clear what the process is, for figuring out what needs to be done on syncdb:

```
    # Get a list of already installed *models* so that references work right.
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
    seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
    created_models = set()
    pending_references = {}

    # Build the manifest of apps and models that are to be synchronized
    all_models = [
        (app.__name__.split('.')[-2],
            [m for m in models.get_models(app, include_auto_created=True)
            if router.allow_syncdb(db, m)])
        for app in models.get_apps()
    ]

    def model_installed(model):
        opts = model._meta
        converter = connection.introspection.table_name_converter
        return not ((converter(opts.db_table) in tables) or
            (opts.auto_created and converter(opts.auto_created._meta.db_table) in tables))

    manifest = SortedDict(
        (app_name, list(filter(model_installed, model_list)))
        for app_name, model_list in all_models
    )
```

At each database driver, there is code to fetch the table names. This is for postgresql:

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
        "Returns a list of table names in the current database."
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT c.relname
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', '')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)""")
        return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```